# Executing a script remotely via python paramiko but don't want to wait until complete to see stdout

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm issuing a script remotely via SSH python paramiko

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = host['connection'].exec_command(command)
```

However, I notice stdout does not get flushed until the remote command is completed. The remote script takes up to 60 seconds to complete but I can really use the data during that time to make decisions. Is it possible to force flush the stdout buffer during the remote command execution?

Comment: How do you read from stdout? Could you provide a [complete minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a dummy command that shows the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script using "python -u script_name.py"  From python's command line args: -u "unbuffered binary stdout and stderr;"

Comment: still buffering until the completion of the remote execution

Comment: This actually looks like the same issue that was reported here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643861/paramiko-channel-stucks-when-reading-large-ouput